# How to measure monotonicity of a list of values

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I need to compare monotonicity of lists of values.

I have $S=(n_1,n_2,...n_n)$, I need a function $\mathrm f(S)$ to return the monotonicity of the S.

$S_1=[1,2,4,4,8]$

$S_2=[8,4,4,2,1]$

$S_3=[2,1,4,4,8]$

$S_4=[1,4,8,2,4]$

Requirement:
$f(S_1) = f(S_2) > f(S_3) > f(S_4)$

### Update Question

$S_5 = [1,4,1,8]$

$S_6 = [1,4,2,8]$

$S_7 = [1,4,4,8]$

$S_8 = [1,4,6,8]$

$S_5 < S_6 < S_7 < S_8$

Comment: $f(S)$ return the length of biggest undecreasing/unincreasing segment + priority by count of different values?

Comment: @Ralor It is one of the models. I can't define it very clearly, this problem is like pattern recognize, I am finding a simple and effective way to measure data smooth and monotonicity, something like statistics.

Comment: you're interested in some algorithmical solution, or just a definition of monotonicity in this case? Mb both of them? In first case - what computational complexity do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have requirement about the complexity of computation of such an index ?

I could suggest:

Let's start with the follow special case : your list is a permutation of $S_n$, seen as a injective list of elements $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. You can count "inversions" ($i$ such that $\sigma (i) > i$) and symmetrize the measure for example $|inversions(\sigma) - \frac{n}{2}|$, such that 0 inversions (increasing list) and $n$ inversions (decreasing list) is maximal, and minimal index is for $\frac{n}{2}$ inversions.

To go back to your general problem (arbitrary list), you could transform your list to a permutation by the following way : sort the list's support and then relabel elements 1,2,...

With your examples : $(1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 2, 4 \rightarrow 3, 4 \rightarrow 4,8 \rightarrow 5)$.

With this relabeling, $S_1$ is $[1,2,3,4,5]$ id est identity, it has 0 inversions so its index is $|0-2.5|=2.5$

$S_2$ is $[5,4,3,2,1]$ has 5 inversions so its index is also $|5-2.5|=2.5$

$S_3$ is $[2,1,3,4,5]$ has 1 inversion so its index is $|1-2.5|=1.5$

$S_4$ is $[1,3,5,2,4]$ has 2 inversions so its index is $|2-2.5|=0.5$ and is maximal.

The dominating cost here comes from the sort (everything else is linear), so computing the index is globally $O(nlog(n))$. The bad point is that for elements that occur multiple times there is a choice to be made (as I did implicitly with 4,4 here - which 4 should I map to 3, and which one to 4 ?) but with a little workout, like choosing the combination such that it maximize the final index, maybe you could adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

How about

$$ -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\lvert n_i-n_{i+1} \rvert}{\max(\lvert n_i \rvert, \lvert n_{i+1} \rvert) } $$

That is: summing relative gaps.

(Considering $0/0$ to be 0.)

Comment: $S_8 < S_6$ for example

Comment: You should take the opposite, does it work?

Comment: Actually, it works fine, except that S7 > S8

Comment: Question: what about [1 2 3 4 5] vs [1 4 9 16 25] vs [1 2 4 8 16]?

Comment: I think the approach is fundamentally wrong; monotonicity is not a local property, you will not be able to define a satisfactory index by summing local contributions independently from each other, no mater what property you choose.

Comment: Can you answer my additional question?

Comment: Can you sort them according to your idea of monotonicity?

Comment: Sure, you could do it as well; that would be (by decreasing order) 1, 3, 2.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that what you mean with monotonicity is how much do the jump vary in size in your sequence. The following definition yields the ordering you requested in your examples:
$$
m(S) = \frac{1}{1 + \left|\mathrm{std}\left\{ (S_{i+1}-S_{i}) \right\}_i\right|}
$$

This is 0 if the sequence jumps between infinities, and 1 if the jumps are all equal (which will also be the case if the sequence is constant).

In case you're wondering about ordering them by step-size as well (ie [0 10 20 30] > [1 2 3 4]), I wouldn't include that in the formula if I were you. I prefer compact, simple formula that tell you something precise, rather than composite that can potentially be difficult to interpret.

Here are two ways to deal with that:

- Order the sequence that have equal monotonicity by the average absolute jump size (procedural approach);
- Replace $\left|\mathrm{std}\left\{ (S_{i+1}-S_{i}) \right\}_i\right|$ by
  $
  \frac{\left|\mathrm{std}\left\{ (S_{i+1}-S_{i}) \right\}_i\right|}{1+\left|S_n-S_1\right|/n}
  $ (composite approach)

Comment: I updated my question base on your answer. add a constraints

Comment: @guilin桂林 Sorry I just saw your update!